# Reference for Algebraic Categories

Tags: category-theory

There seems to be a useful result saying the forgetful functor from algebraic categories reflects limits and filtered colimits. My problem is that I haven't been able to find a source which both defines algebraic categories and proves this theorem.

In volume II of Borceux, he does define an algebraic category as one which is equivalent to the category of models of an algebraic theory (Lawvere theory). He proceeds to characterize them in quite a difficult theorem, without which it wouldn't even be obvious that, say, $\mathsf{Grp,Ab}$ are algebraic. Is this the common definition, and if so, how does one prove the result above? If not, where can I find this result?

Comment: Lawvere theories are certainly one way of going about this. It's quite standard. Once you have a concrete description like that it is easy to check your claim by hand.

Comment: @ZhenLin it's not easy for me. In the terminology of Borceux, Vol II, one can obtain from a a presentation of the theory of groups a Lawvere theory. This lawvere theory is not the category of groups though. I do not understand how to show the forgetful functor from $\mathsf{Grp}$ to $\mathsf{Set}$ reflects limits and filtered colimits using these notions (I want this result for $\mathsf{Ab,Rng,Ring}$ etc. aswell).

Comment: Look at the book "Algebraic Theories: A Categorical Introduction to General Algebra" by Adamek et al. https://books.google.es/books?id=siNlAn8Bm30C

Comment: @boumol thank you very much, I think this is exactly what I'm looking for. Judging from the first few definitions, it seems Borceux does pretty much the same thing. I guess the characterization of algebraic categories is just not a simple thing.

Comment: The characterisation of algebraic categories is easy if you accept the notion of Lawvere theory. If you don't, then you will have to do more work. Anyway, fix a Lawvere theory $\mathcal{T}$. Then a model of $\mathcal{T}$ is a functor $\mathcal{T} \to \mathbf{Set}$ that preserves finite products. The category $\mathsf{Mod} (\mathcal{T})$ is a full subcategory of $[\mathcal{T}, \mathbf{Set}]$. All you have to do is show that the inclusion creates limits and filtered colimits, which really is not difficult.

Comment: @ZhenLin I accept the notion of Lawvere theory, but I don't feel the characterization is easy. I will study the proofs and perhaps I will eventually feel that way too :) I do not see from the theorem (3.9.1 in Borceux, vol II) that all that needs to be done is to show the inclusion creates limits and filtered colimits.

Comment: @boumol: Why not writing your answer as an answer, so that it can be accepted?

Answer (score 0):

One easy proof, which doesn't appear to have been mentioned, is to use the correspondence between finitary algebraic theories, and finitary monads on $\mathbf{Set}$. The category of models for a finitary algebraic theory is concretely equivalent to the category of algebras for the corresponding finitary monad. Furthermore, the forgetful functor from the category of algebras for a finitary monad creates limits and filtered colimits (e.g. see [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/colimits+in+categories+of+algebras)).